# bundler,gems---change from newer version according to requirement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i'm new to ruby on rails.The problem i'm facing is
I've made a project on ruby on rails(rails 3.2.11)(ruby 1.9.3)
The gems i'm using have higher version.

Now i've to commit the project on beta version of my site.

In the beta version,the gems are installed but they are of lower version and of course i can't update the gems there cause' other projects are dependent on them and they will stop working.

Please help me--

Here is my gem file

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'devise', '1.1.rc0'

gem 'json'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

and here's my environment.rb

```
#### Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

#### Initialize the rails application
OfficeSpace::Application.initialize!
```

Please tell me how i can commit this project on beta.(Tell what changes i've to make in my project as i can't make any on beta)

These are the gems beta is using

```
abstract (1.0.0)

actionmailer (3.2.8, 3.0.4, 2.3.6)

actionpack (3.2.8, 3.0.9, 3.0.4, 2.3.6)

actionwebservice (1.2.6)

activemodel (3.2.8, 3.0.9, 3.0.4, 3.0.3)

activerecord (3.2.8, 3.0.4, 2.3.6, 2.3.2)

activerecord-import (0.2.9)

activeresource (3.2.8, 3.0.4, 2.3.6, 2.3.2)

activesupport (3.2.8, 3.0.4, 3.0.3, 2.3.6)

addressable (2.3.2, 2.2.6)

algorithms (0.3.0)

amazon-ec2 (0.9.17, 0.9.15)

ar-extensions (0.9.5, 0.9.2)

arel (3.0.2, 3.0.0, 2.0.10)

atk (1.1.6)

atom (0.3)

attr_required (0.0.5)

autoparse (0.3.2, 0.2.3)

aweber (1.5.0)

aws-s3 (0.6.2)

aws-ses (0.4.4, 0.4.2)

bayes_motel (0.1.0)

bitly (0.6.1)

blekko (0.0.3)

bluecloth (2.1.0)

builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)

bundler (1.0.10)

cairo (1.12.3)

childprocess (0.3.6)

cobravsmongoose (0.0.2)

columnize (0.3.2)

configatron (2.10.0)

cookiejar (0.3.0)

crack (0.1.8)

createsend (2.5.0)

curb (0.7.18, 0.7.10)

daemon_controller (0.2.5)

daemons (1.1.9)

data_objects (0.10.7)

diff-lcs (1.1.3)

dm-core (1.2.0)

dm-do-adapter (1.2.0)

dm-sqlite-adapter (1.2.0)

do_sqlite3 (0.10.7)

domain_name (0.5.3)

em-http-request (1.0.3)

em-socksify (0.2.1)

em-twitter (0.1.4)

erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)

eventmachine (1.0.0.rc.4)

extlib (0.9.15)

facebooker2 (0.0.11, 0.0.10)

faraday (0.7.4)

faraday_middleware (0.8.8, 0.7.0)

fastercsv (1.5.5)

fastthread (1.0.7)

fb_graph (2.6.4, 2.4.1)

feedtools (0.2.29)

ffi (1.2.0)

file-tail (1.0.5)

gcm (0.0.2)

gcm_on_rails (0.1.3)

geocoder (1.1.6, 1.1.3)

geoip (1.1.2)

geokit (1.6.5)

gibbon (0.3.5)

glib2 (1.1.6)

google-api-client (0.4.6, 0.3.0)

google-search (1.0.2)

google_alerts (0.0.1)

google_plus (0.2.0)

googleajax (1.0.1)

googlebase (0.2.1)

googlereader (0.0.4)

grabz_it (0.0.4)

grabzit (1.1.0)

has_vimeo_video (0.0.5)

hashie (1.2.0, 1.1.0)

hashr (0.0.22)

highline (1.6.2)

hike (1.2.1)

hominid (3.0.2)

hpricot (0.8.3)

htmlentities (4.3.1)

httmultiparty (0.3.6)

http_parser.rb (0.5.3)

httpadapter (1.0.1)

httparty (0.8.3)

httpauth (0.2.0)

httpclient (2.2.4)

hubspot (0.0.2)

i18n (0.6.0, 0.5.0, 0.4.0)

imgkit (1.3.7)

instagram (0.8.5)

journey (1.0.4, 1.0.3)

json (1.5.1, 1.4.6)

jwt (0.1.5, 0.1.4)

koala (1.5.0)

launchy (2.1.2, 2.0.5)

libwebsocket (0.1.7.1)

libxml-ruby (1.1.4)

linecache (0.43)

linkedin (0.3.7)

locale (2.0.5)

mail (2.4.4, 2.4.0, 2.2.19)

mechanize (2.5.1)

memcache-client (1.8.5)

mime-types (1.18, 1.16)

mislav-will_paginate (2.3.11)

mogli (0.0.37)

multi_json (1.3.7, 1.0.0)

multi_xml (0.5.3, 0.2.2)

multipart-post (1.1.3)

mysql (2.8.1)

n_gram (0.0.1)

net-http-digest_auth (1.2.1)

net-http-persistent (2.7)

nokogiri (1.5.5, 1.4.4, 1.4.3.1)

nori (1.1.3)

ntlm-http (0.1.1)

oauth (0.4.5, 0.4.4, 0.4.3)

oauth2 (0.8.0, 0.5.2, 0.5.0)

omniauth (1.0.1)

omnicontacts (0.2.1)

pango (1.1.6)

passenger (3.0.2, 2.2.15)

payment (1.0.1)

pkg-config (1.1.4)

polyglot (0.3.3, 0.3.2, 0.3.1)

r_hapi (0.1.2)

rack (1.4.4, 1.4.1, 1.2.5, 1.2.3, 1.1.0)

rack-cache (1.2, 1.1)

rack-mount (0.6.14, 0.6.13)

rack-oauth2 (1.0.0, 0.14.2)

rack-openid (1.3.1)

rack-protection (1.3.2)

rack-ssl (1.3.2)

rack-test (0.6.1, 0.5.7)

rails (3.0.9, 3.0.4, 2.3.6)

railties (3.2.8, 3.0.9, 3.0.4)

rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2, 0.8.7)

rbx-require-relative (0.0.5)

rdoc (3.12, 3.9.1)

RedCloth (4.2.8)

rest-client (1.6.7)

rest-open-uri (1.0.0)

retryable (1.3.1)

rspec (2.11.0)

rspec-core (2.11.1)

rspec-expectations (2.11.1)

rspec-mocks (2.11.1)

ruby-debug (0.10.4)

ruby-debug-base (0.10.4)

ruby-hmac (0.4.0)

ruby-openid (2.2.2)

ruby-openid-apps-discovery (1.2.0)

rubygems-update (1.5.0)

rubyzip (0.9.9)

sanitize (2.0.3)

selenium-webdriver (2.27.1)

signet (0.4.1)

simple-rss (1.2.3)

simple_oauth (0.1.9, 0.1.5)

simple_youtube (3.0.0)

sinatra (1.3.3)

spell_checker (0.0.2)

sprockets (2.1.3, 2.1.2)

spruz (0.2.5)

sqlite3 (1.3.6, 1.3.4)

stemmer (1.0.1)

supermodel (0.1.6)

syntax (1.0.0)

thor (0.16.0, 0.14.6)

tilt (1.3.3)

tmail (1.2.7.1)

treetop (1.4.10, 1.4.9)

trollop (2.0)

truncate_html (0.5.5)

tweetstream (2.1.0)

twitter (1.6.2)

twitter_oauth (0.4.3)

tzinfo (0.3.33, 0.3.29, 0.3.24)

unf (0.0.5)

unf_ext (0.0.5)

uuidtools (2.1.3)

vapir-common (1.10.1)

vapir-firefox (1.10.1)

vimeo (1.5.3)

webrobots (0.0.13)

websocket (1.0.4)

whatlanguage (1.0.0)

will_paginate (2.3.11)

xml-simple (1.1.1, 1.0.14, 1.0.12)

yajl-ruby (1.1.0)

yamler (0.1.0)

yard (0.8.3)

youtube_it (2.1.7)

youtube_search (0.1.6)
```

And these are the gems my project is using

Gems included by the bundle:

```
  * actionmailer (3.2.11)

  * actionpack (3.2.11)

  * activemodel (3.2.11)

  * activerecord (3.2.11)

  * activeresource (3.2.11)

  * activesupport (3.2.11)

  * arel (3.0.2)

  * builder (3.0.4)

  * bundler (1.2.3)

  * coffee-rails (3.2.2)

  * coffee-script (2.2.0)

  * coffee-script-source (1.4.0)

  * devise (1.1.rc0)

  * erubis (2.7.0)

  * execjs (1.4.0)

  * hike (1.2.1)

  * i18n (0.6.1)

  * journey (1.0.4)

  * jquery-rails (2.2.1)

  * json (1.7.7)

  * mail (2.4.4)

  * mime-types (1.21)

  * multi_json (1.6.0)

  * mysql2 (0.3.11)

  * polyglot (0.3.3)

  * rack (1.4.5)

  * rack-cache (1.2)

  * rack-ssl (1.3.3)

  * rack-test (0.6.2)

  * rails (3.2.11)

  * railties (3.2.11)

  * rake (10.0.3)

  * rdoc (3.12.1)

  * sass (3.2.5)

  * sass-rails (3.2.6)

  * sprockets (2.2.2)

  * thor (0.17.0)

  * tilt (1.3.3)

  * treetop (1.4.12)

  * tzinfo (0.3.35)

  * uglifier (1.3.0)

  * warden (0.10.7)

  * will_paginate (3.0.4)
```

So you see there's incompatibility.How to resolve that issue??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use rvm.  It allows you to have multiple `gemsets` that you can assign to a project, giving you the ability to pick what version of gems each project uses.  Check out: https://rvm.io